# Android, Http Post not performing update

Tags: android, xml, web-services, http-post

I want to update data via web service in Android. performing POST operation for the same But it is catching Exception when executing  " `httpClient.execute(httppost)` " and exception message is NULL
any one please help me!

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://myurl");

try {
  String xmln = XMLfunctions.getXMLn();
  String Authorization= "Basic usrnameandpasswrd";

  httppost.setHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
  httppost.setHeader("Authorization", Authorization);
  httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");

  int ln=xmln.length();
  String sln="";
  sln=sln+ln;

  httppost.setHeader("Content-Length", sln);
  //Add your data  

  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();   
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserID", "0085b488"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("FName", "Prasanth"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("LName", "san"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", "prasanth.raghavan@xyz.com"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Image", "image encryptdAAAAASUVORK5CYII="));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Culture", "en_IN"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Timezone", "5.0000"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("DaylightSavings", "false"));
  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PhoneNumber", "9999999999"));

  StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(nameValuePairs.toString(), "UTF-8");
  httppost.setEntity(entity);
  BasicHttpResponse responseGet =(BasicHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httppost);

  //tried this too
  //HttpResponse responseGet = httpClient.execute(httppost);
       // Execute HTTP Post Request
    // not executing    HttpEntity httpEntity = responseGet.getEntity();
  // not executing String line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  String err=e.getMessage(); // err = NULL Here
}
catch (IOException e) 
      { // TODO Auto-generated catch block }
```

Comment: So..why do you set a Content-Length & Content-Type in the POST & then encode something **completely different** into the StringEntity that you supply? This looks pretty broken from the get-go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the following permission in your manifest, outside of your application tag:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: its already there in manifest! i think i need to set "httpbody"